# Mysql: inserting record in One table taking too long

Tags: mysql, insert-update

In one of the tables I have approximately 80,000 records and when I am inserting a record, it takes too long. When I delete records from that table, it works fine.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Need a bit more info. Amount of columns, indexes on the table, etc.

Comment: What's the query you're using? `DELETE FROM table WHERE id = 1` will be significantly faster than `DELETE FROM table WHERE textField LIKE '%foo%' OR textField REGEX 'bar[^\+]'`

Answer (score 0):

Problems with insertion are usually due to too many indexes, or a trigger that is running on insert.  Look into those areas:

- Make sure that you are only indexing things that need to be indexed.
- Ensure that any triggers are efficient, or ...
- Remove the trigger(s) and implement the functionality in another way.